# how to save a belongs_to relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models

```
class Course < AR::B
   belongs_to :teacher
end

class Teacher < AR::B
   has_one :course
end
```

So my table `courses` has one field `teacher_id`. I've a dropdown on courses to choose the teacher that works like a charm.

But I want to add a dropdown on the EDIT TEACHER screen also to change the course. I've tried with `f.collection_select :course, Courses.all, :id, :name`. This displays the dropdown, and on the controller:

```
teacher_params[:course] = Course.find(teacher_params[:course])
```

Beacause I was receiving an error `Expecting Course got String.` If i just try with `@teacher.save`. But this don't works neither

What is the right way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In your form, be sure you are setting the database column (not the association)

```
= f.collection_select :course_id, Courses.all, :id, :name
                             ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

on the edit page you should find the course by id and either assign the `teacher_id` directly, or find the teacher model as well and set it to `Course#teacher`.

assuming your params come back with something like

```
{ course: { id: 1, teacher_id: 5 } }
```

for option 1, your controller might look like

```
@course = Course.find(teacher_params[:id])
@course.teacher_id = teacher_params[:teacher_id]
```

or for option 2

```
@course = Course.find(teacher_params[:id])
@teacher = teacher_params[:teacher_id]
@course.teacher = @teacher
```

now saving the course should be fine

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
class Teacher < AR::B
   has_one :courses
end
```

you are using :course, it must be plural
and second thing f.collection_select :course, **Courses.all,** :id, :name
this is wrong here is correct way

```
f.collection_select :course, Course.all, :id, :name
```